# Can requests via Ajax to make direct db queries ever be made secure?

Tags: ajax, django, security

Suppose you would format your urls so that you could make direct model queries with a request using Ajax.

*Making a query in Django*:

```
MyModel.objects.get(id=4)
```

*Making a query via request to url using Ajax*:

```
/ajax/my-model/get/id/4/
```

The problem is that this presents a huge security problem, any user that knows how to make requests via Ajax could query the database by recognising that the url corresponds to a query of a specific model. However, if these kind of queries could be made secure, it would allow for much more well structured/reuseable client side code imo.

But I simply don't see how this can be made secure. I just want to make sure if this suspicion is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, such views will be protected by its authentication mechanism. It is possible to design the view so it will only allow specific users to query specific queries.

Comment: Well, it would still not be secure if an authenticated user can make any query he likes. Do you want to let an authenticated user query e.g. information about any other user he wants? I don't think so.

Comment: Taking your example above, the Django view needs to check if id==4 is viewable by the user or not. For e.g. if it is an order, then only the person who made the order will see it. Others should see a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Never trust input from the client. I think this is a very general rule in web development and applies to any request the client does. I think you have a couple options here:

- use [Django's internal Authorization mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization). This is not authentication! Like this you can limit resources to be accessed to specific users only. Also look into [reusable django apps](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/authorization/), which seem to take some complexity out of that topic.
- validate every input from the client. This is mostly for requests which are supposed to change data).
- use an API framework like [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [django-restframework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), which are easily plugable with your models and offer authentication and authorization out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for these options! I already started to look at a rest framework because of another thread I read, I'm glad I at least had the insight to see that a sort of CRUD structure in ajax calls could lead to more maintainable code (or at least code that has a clearer separation of concerns).